# VBA editing bookmark in a building block

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have an Access project to create a word document from a template.  I use buildingBlocks in the template.  Each buildingBlock has a bookmark.  I am trying to figure out how to replace the bookmark with text, from a database.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Label87_Click()
    Screen.MousePointer = 11
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim PauseTime, Start, Timer As Integer
    Dim wrkCurrent As DAO.Workspace

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False 'True is visible

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Some SQL Select COde"
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set wrkCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)

    objWord.Documents.Add ("C:\test\myTemplate.docx")
    If (Not rst.EOF) Then
        With rst
            Do Until .EOF
        On Error GoTo Trans_Error
        Dim objBB As BuildingBlock
        Dim objTemplate As Template
        Dim bookMark As bookMark

        Set objTemplate = objWord.ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
        Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("MyBB")

        objBB.Insert objWord.Selection.Range, RichText:=True            
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BM_in_BB").Select
        'error occurs here, where I try to change the text
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "A Test" 


             .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
    End If

    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\test\MyNewDocument.docx")
    objWord.PrintOut
    objWord.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Screen.MousePointer = 0
Trans_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dbs = Nothing
    objWord.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Screen.MousePointer = 0
    Exit Sub
Trans_Error:
    MsgBox Err.description
        Resume Trans_Exit    

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't do anything with the bookmark while it's in a BuildingBlock. You first need to insert the BB, then you can write to the bookmark.

Comment: I've tried that as well.  I get an errors saying "Object Doesnt support this property or method.  I'll update my code to reflect that.

Comment: Working with Selection is always tricky... WHAT exactly is selected at this point? Note also that it would be better for you to integrate this back into your original question. And keep in mind that not everyone you deal with is going to be in the same time-zone / on-line at the same time you are. Sometimes, you have to be patient. AND you need to remember to alert people using @name, otherwise a reply in Comments won't be seen.

Comment: @Cindy Meister  thanks Cindy.  I wasn't sure if this would be considered a different question, as the first one did not have to do with BuildingBlocks.  It was in that post that the option to use BuildingBlocks was suggested.  In the past I have been told to create new threads when the question deviates from the original.  Regardless, I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: One issue I have found is that, if I manually create a document and add a building block, which has a bookmark in it, the bookmark is visible (if I have the setting turned on).  But, if I use my code to add the building block, the bookmark is just text (not surrounded by brackets).  Any ideas on why?

Comment: Probably, the original bookmark name is being honored and the one being inserted lost. Two bookmarks can't have the same name. Or the setting for seeing bookmarks has been turned off (so none would show). The circumstances around what you're doing aren't clear enough to say which it might be.